# Ошибка "You need to find .cpp to view the source for the current call stack frame" при отладке

Tags: c++, visual-studio, отладка

> You need to find appmodul.cpp to view the source for the current call
>   stack frame

Вот такую ошибку выдаёт, когда я начинаю дебажить проект. При этом solution билдится и проект работает. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Компилироваться будет, работать будет. Но чтобы провалиться внутрь кода -- нужны исходники этого кода. Если это ваш код -- нажмите кнопку Browse и укажите файл (этот выбор запомнится и последующих запусках спрашивать больше не будет). Если не ваш -- просто не заходите внутрь по F11, а проходите по F10 такие строки.